# How to jump from "dds esp" memory dump in WinDBG MiniDump to source code?

Tags: com, windbg

Suppose I have a crash dump in WinDBG with an unusable call stack (maybe a MiniDump). But using the console, I can get some approximation of the called code with a sequence of commands like:

```
dds esp
dds
dds
kb=<mem address>
<etc>
```

Once I get some hints about the function calls in memory like:

```
MyDLL!MyClass::MyFunctionName (@D:\build\<path>\CodeFile.cls @ LineNumber)
```

Is there a way to get WinDBG to open the Source pane to that code file at the right line? I always find myself pulling up a separate IDE/editor to match it, but it would be nice if it could jump to the line, the way it can from the Call Stack pane by double-clicking the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564622(v=vs.85).aspx) allows you to open source code associated with a particular address

Comment: This seems to be definitely on the right track. Is there a way to get it to open to the right line number in the source file? I've tried syntax like: ".open -m LineNumber FilePath" and ".open FilePath LineNumber" - the first one opens the correct file, but can't resolve the line number.

Comment: ".open -a addr" opens the right file at the right line for me. Do you have your source search path set correctly?